# React Native: What does it mean to 'redirect user via HTTP Post with variables x y z"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, payment, payment-processing

I am reading [this documentation](https://developer.moneris.com/Documentation/NA/E-Commerce%20Solutions/Hosted%20Solutions/Hosted%20Payment%20Page) on doing Moneris payments in my React Native app, and in the "Hosted Paypage With Data Preload" section it says "redirect the shopper via an HTTPS post with the variables below to the Moneris Hosted Pay Page".
What does this mean? I can redirect a user to a website with a Webview, but does this mean that I should include the given variables as parameters in the URL I redirect them to?